# Checking if JSON has unparseable curft - jQuery .ajax dataFilter

Tags: jquery, json, security, csrf

Using:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataFilter: function(data, type) {
        if (type === 'json') {
            data.replace('for (;;);', '');
            return JSON.parse(data);
        }

        return data;
    }
});
```

To process json for the unparseable cruft - `for(;;);`  - for json security:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/samples/data_region/JSONParserSample.html

But what I would like to do is for the .ajax function to check if the json has the unparseable cruft and if so, replace it and return it otherwise just return it.

That way, I can reuse the function as is across the site - and some json will have the cruft and others won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only reason your dataFilter isn't working is that the `.replace` method doesn't work in-place on strings; you have to return the result to a new string, or reassign the string to the output of its replace method.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataFilter: function(data, type) {
        if (type === 'json') {
            data = data.replace('for (;;);', '');
            return JSON.parse(data);
        }

        return data;
    }
});
```

Comment: would it make more sense to use converter?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using `dataFilter` for this. Are you having problems with it? Does your filter method still not work, even after the change I suggested?

Comment: Isn't `dataFilter` deprecated in favor of converters?

Comment: Not officially (as far as I can tell!), but I suppose it might eventually be. You could use converters just as easily.

Comment: Anyone used `converters` for this scenario? and how does it work - in the ajaxSetup?